# Display Default Image if wasn't picked by Image Picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image picker function, that picks image from gallery and then assigns that to **_image** variable which is String. It converts it to base64 because that is what was necessary. I want to know how would I go about getting the default image from assets as the _image if no image was picked (picked image is null). Here's the code and things I've tried commented out, it is under **else** in code:

```
  Future _getImage() async {
PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    final file = File(pickedFile.path);
    _image = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
  } else {
    //if image wasn't picked, get the default one from assets
    print('No image selected.');
    // final file = File(AssetImage('assets/defaultfood.jpg').toString());
    // _image = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
    //final file = File('assets/defaultfood.jpg');
    //_image = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
    
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**add image placeholder like this ternary condition**

```
child: pickedFile == null ? Image.asset("assets/images/man_user.png",height: 100, width: 100): Image.file(pickedFile, height: 100, width: 100),
```

Comment: You're right, actually I figured it out myself, I had a derp moment for a few minutes, just couldn't figure it out. Thank you anyways!